# How to populate a ListView with List of School that Teacher work

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cardview

Hello Guys I have a doubt. How to populate a ListView where I have 1 teacher that work in several university school.

For example:

** The Teacher Jonh Braz works in school harvard university, in yale university and university of washington.

** The Teacher Bill Hans works in school Harvard university and yale university.

I need show one card for each school that the teacher works.

in my example I need show on app 3 cards for teacher John(because John works in 3 schooll) and 2 cards for teacher Bill(because bill works in 2 scholl)

follow my class Teacher

```
public class Teacher{

   private int id;
   private String nome;
   private private List<School> schoolList;

    */ gets and sets here /*
}
```

follow my class School

```
 public class School{

   private int id;
   private String schoolName;

    */ gets and sets here /*
}
```

Now I need pupulate a listView with Adapter for show 1 card by school that the teacher works.

I don't know how do it

Follow my class Adapter

```
 public class TeacherAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TeacherAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Teacher> mTeacherList;

    public TeacherAdapter(List<Teacher> data) {
    mTeacherList = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView =             LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.teacher_item, parent,        false);
         return new ViewHolder(itemView);
     }

     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     Teacher teacher = mTeacherList.get(position);

     for (int i = 0; i < teacher.getSchoolList().size(); i++) {
         holder.textViewTeacherNome.setText(teacher.getNome());
             holder.textViewSchoolName.setText(teacher.getConsultorioList().get(i).getName())   ;
       }
   }

     @Override
     public int getItemCount() {
     return mTeacherList.size();
  }

  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

      public TextView textViewTeeacherNome;
      public TextView textViewSchoolName;


      public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewTeacherNome = (TextView)      itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name_teacher);
           textViewSchoolName = (TextView)      itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name_school);
       }
   }
```

}

This class not work, show only a card by teacher and I need that show me a card by school that the tacher works.

Answer (score 0):

ListView is designed to show a List of custom objects, each object represents a corresponding view item.
In your case, I'd recommend you create a new class which wraps both Teacher and School objects.

```
public class TeacherSchoolWrapper {
    private Teacher mTeacher;
    private School mSchool;

    public TeacherSchoolWrapper(Teacher teacher, School school) {
        mTeacher = teacher;
        mSchool = school;
    }

    /* Getters and setters go here...*/
}
```

When you initialize your data, create a ArrayList of TeacherSchoolWrapper, and then fill in with your teachers and schools' data.

```
public ArrayList<TeacherSchoolWrapper> initialize(List<Teacher> teachers) {
    ArrayList<TeacherSchoolWrapper> wrappers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Teacher teacher : teachers) {
        // Create wrappers which contain both teacher and school
        for (School school : teacher.getSchoolList()) {
            wrappers.add(new TeacherSchoolWrapper(teacher, school));
        }
    }
    return wrappers;
}
```

Create the adapter class which interprets data.

```
public class TeacherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TeacherSchoolWrapper> {
    public TeacherAdapter(ArrayList<TeacherSchoolWrapper> wrappers) {
        super(this, 0, wrappers);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null);
        }
        TeacherSchoolWrapper wrapper = getItem(position);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        textView1.setText(wrapper.getTeacher().getName());
        textView2.setText(wrapper.getSchool().getName());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.